# Entity Framework 7 multiple levels of child tables

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm just getting started with EF7 (CORE) and am struggling to find the right implementation of the following. Say I have a Table with multiple child tables, which in turn have grandchild tables (and these in turn have foreign key tables).  If I wanted access to everything I'd need something like this

```
 TABLE_A.Include(c => c.TABLE_B).ThenInclude(co => co.TABLE_C)
                                .ThenInclude(coi => coi.TABLE_D)
                                .ThenInclude(coia => coia.TABLE_E)
        .Include(c => c.TABLE_B).ThenInclude(co => co.TABLE_F)
                                .ThenInclude(coa => coa.TABLE_G)
                                .ThenInclude(coaAcc => coaAcc.TABLE_H)
                                .ThenInclude(coaAccInt => coaAccInt.TABLE_D)
                                .ThenInclude(coaAccIntAgent => coaAccIntAgent.TABLE_E)
```

Now I understand the necessity for chaining the includes to include all of my child tables...but I look at the SQL it fires behind the scenes and its firing off 11 SQL statements.  This seems terribly inefficient.

Is this the best way to be doing this?  I have now received a new requirement to add 3 more child tables to TABLE_B...so I'll need more includes..and hence more selects running behind the scenes.

I understand the logic behind what I'm doing..and understand lazy loading isn't currently supported in EF7, but this doesn't seem like a very efficient way of doing things when I could write a stored procedure that does it in one go.

Are there best practices for things like this or something I'm not grasping about how to use EF7 to do what I need?

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

add this extension method to your project, Load method exist in ef 6.x, but not implemented yet in ef core:

```
public static void Load<TSource, TDestination>(this EntityEntry<TSource> entry, Expression<Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TDestination>>> path, Expression<Func<TDestination, TSource>> pathBack = null) where TSource : class where TDestination : class
{
    var entity = entry.Entity;
    var context = entry.Context;
    var entityType = context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(TSource));
    var keys = entityType.GetKeys();
    var keyValues = context.GetEntityKey(entity);
    var query = context.Set<TDestination>() as IQueryable<TDestination>;
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TDestination), "x");
    PropertyInfo foreignKeyProperty = null;

    if (pathBack == null)
    {
        foreignKeyProperty = typeof(TDestination).GetProperties().Single(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(TSource));
    }
    else
    {
        foreignKeyProperty = (pathBack.Body as MemberExpression).Member as PropertyInfo;
    }

    var i = 0;

    foreach (var property in keys.SelectMany(x => x.Properties))
    {
        var keyValue = keyValues[i];

        var expression = Expression.Lambda(
            Expression.Equal(
                Expression.Property(Expression.Property(parameter, foreignKeyProperty.Name), property.Name),
                Expression.Constant(keyValue)),
            parameter) as Expression<Func<TDestination, bool>>;

        query = query.Where(expression);

        i++;
    }

    var list = query.ToList();

    var prop = (path.Body as MemberExpression).Member as PropertyInfo;
    prop.SetValue(entity, list);
}

public static object[] GetEntityKey<T>(this DbContext context, T entity) where T : class
{
    var state = context.Entry(entity);
    var metadata = state.Metadata;
    var key = metadata.FindPrimaryKey();
    var props = key.Properties.ToArray();

    return props.Select(x => x.GetGetter().GetClrValue(entity)).ToArray();
}
```

then whenever you need each of navigation properties, before use first call load (just once for any navigation properties) method as fallowing:

```
//for first item
var item = TABLE_A.First(); 
context.Entry(item ).Load(b => b.TABLE_B);
```

Depending on your use case, can Include or ThenInclude some of navigation in first query that load TABLE_A.

Load extension method [Source Link](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/implementing-missing-features-in-entity-framework-core-part-2) with more examples

Comment: How does that work for collections?  TABLE_A is a collection...and each entity has a list of TABLE_B.  If i were to use

`_context.Entry(<List of table A>).Load(b => b.<Table_B>);`

I get the error
'IQueryable<TABLE_A>' does not contain a definition for 'TABLE_B' and no extension method 'TABLE_B' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable<Customer>' could be found

Comment: _context.Entry get single object only, you load first all TABLE_A list, and whenever needed per item in TABLE_A list, use this code ex: var item =TABLE_A.First(); context.Entry(item).Load(b => b.TABLE_B);< In fact, In fact, similar to LazyLoadining but explicit load navigation

Comment: Wow that's a terrible solution.  If i render 300 items in a view, and display the data from 10 FK tables, I'd be effectively running 3000 queries behind the scenes.

Comment: In entity framework two way exist for query data, eager loading that you use in question, but extrem data load and query occur, and lazy loading that i suggest in my answer, depending on your problem ,select on way or trade of between two way,